# Adjust line spacing after using \begin{adjustwidth}

Tags: line-spacing, adjustwidth

My document is double spaced, and is creating a weird space after I indent my theorem below my definition.

This is my code;

```
\begin{definition}

\textbf{Modulus}: the remainder after dividing one number by another

\end{definition}

\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5em}{0pt}
      
\begin{theorem}\label{theo: modulo}
    
The \textbf{modulus} of a congruence $a=b(mod m)$ is the number $m$, with $m$>1 It is the "base" with respect to which a congruence is computed (i.e., m gives the number of multiples of a that are "thrown out"). \cite{mur}
    
\end{theorem}  

\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5em}{0pt}   
    
\begin{example}
    
Example of modulus, when computing the time of day using a 12-hour clock obtained by adding four hours to 9:00, the answer, 1:00, is obtained by taking 9+4=1(mod 12). 
    
\end{example} 

\end{adjustwidth}
```

[image: Why is my line spacing like this?]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please extend your code fragment to selfcontained document, which we can compile as it is. In preamble it should load only to code fragment relevant packages.

Comment: Into your fragment there are many mistakes starting from $a=b(mod m)$, $m$>1, etc.